# SQL Server PHP PDO exception: could not find driver

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2

Estoy intentando conectarme a una base de datos en SQL Server 2008 desde Yii2. Mi versión de php es 5.6.31

Este es mi archivo de configuración en `db.php`

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mssql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=softwareoperacional',
    'username' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'admin123',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Recibo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php:646

Informacion adicional

- Yii vesion 2.0.12
- PHP version 5.6.31
- Operating system Windows 7 sp1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu servidor no tiene habilitado ningún driver para conectar a SQL Server.
Según la versión de tu PHP, deberías instalar el driver SQLSRV provisto por Microsoft ([instrucciones en la documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver)) y habilitarlo en php_ini agregando la línea:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

(Esta línea debe apuntar al dll que corresponda) y luego reiniciar Apache.

[Esta otra página (en inglés)](http://bendustries.co/wp/setting-up-xampp-to-work-with-mssql/) contiene instrucciones detalladas para habilitar el driver SQL Server en XAMPP.

Comment: Mi version de php es la 5.6.31 ya agregue la linea en php.ini pero aun sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Haz un `phpinfo()` ¿te aparece SQLSRV dentro de la sección PDO? Si es así, el driver quedó bien instalado. ¿Modificaste la línea de conexión en tu configuración? Debería quedar algo así como `'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:Server=127.0.0.1;Database=softwareoperacional'`

Comment: Si amigo en `phpinfo()` me aparece sqlsrv esta correctamente instalado el driver

Comment: ¿Y la línea `dsn` en la configuración? ¿Te aparece algún mensaje de error al intentar conectar?